# IndexError: Target is out of bounds

Tags: python, pytorch, text-classification, bert-language-model

I am currently trying to replicate the article

https://towardsdatascience.com/text-classification-with-bert-in-pytorch-887965e5820f

to get an introduction to PyTorch and BERT.

I used some own sample corpus and corresponding tragets as practise, but the code throws the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-8577755f37de> in <module>()
    201 LR = 1e-6
    202 
--> 203 trainer(model, df_train, df_val, LR, EPOCHS)

3 frames
<ipython-input-4-8577755f37de> in trainer(model, train_data, val_data, learning_rate, epochs)
    162                 output = model(input_id, mask)
    163 
--> 164                 batch_loss = criterion(output, torch.max(train_label,1)[1])
    165                 total_loss_train += batch_loss.item()
    166 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py in forward(self, input, target)
   1150         return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
   1151                                ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction,
-> 1152                                label_smoothing=self.label_smoothing)
   1153 
   1154 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction, label_smoothing)
   2844     if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   2845         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 2846     return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
   2847 
   2848 

IndexError: Target 32 is out of bounds.
```

The code is mostly identical to the one in the article, except of course the more extensive lable-dict.

Orginial:

```
labels = {'business':0,
          'entertainment':1,
          'sport':2,
          'tech':3,
          'politics':4
          }
```

Mine:

```
labels = 
{'Macroeconomics': 0,
 'Microeconomics': 1,
 'Labor Economics': 2,
 'Subnational Fiscal Issues': 3,
 'Econometrics': 4,
 'International Economics': 5,
 'Financial Economics': 6,
 'Health, Education, and Welfare': 7,
 'Public Economics': 8,
 'Development and Growth': 9,
 'Industrial Organization': 10,
 'Other': 11,
 'Environmental and Resource Economics': 12,
 'History': 13,
 'Regional and Urban Economics': 14,
 'Development Economics': 15,
 'Corporate Finance': 16,
 'Children': 17,
 'Labor Studies': 18,
 'Economic Fluctuations and Growth': 19,
 'Economics of Aging': 20,
 'Economics of Education': 21,
 'International Trade and Investment': 22,
 'Asset Pricing': 23,
 'Health Economics': 24,
 'Law and Economics': 25,
 'International Finance and Macroeconomics': 26,
 'Monetary Economics': 27,
 'Technical Working Papers': 28,
 'Political Economy': 29,
 'Development of the American Economy': 30,
 'Health Care': 31,
 'Productivity, Innovation, and Entrepreneurship': 32}
```

Code:

```
class Dataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):

    def __init__(self, df):

        self.labels = torch.LongTensor([labels[label] for label in df["category"]])
        self.texts = [tokenizer(text, 
                               padding='max_length', max_length = 512, truncation=True,
                                return_tensors="pt") for text in df['text']]

    def classes(self):
        return self.labels

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)

    def get_batch_labels(self, idx):
        # Fetch a batch of labels
        return np.array(self.labels[idx])

    def get_batch_texts(self, idx):
        # Fetch a batch of inputs
        return self.texts[idx]

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_texts = self.get_batch_texts(idx)
        batch_y = np.array(range(0,len(labels)))

        return batch_texts, batch_y
    
#Splitting the sample into trainingset, validationset and testset (80,10,10)
np.random.seed(112)
df_train, df_val, df_test = np.split(df.sample(frac=1, random_state=42), 
                                     [int(.8*len(df)), int(.9*len(df))])

print(len(df_train),len(df_val), len(df_test))


from torch import nn

class BertClassifier(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, dropout=0.5):

        super(BertClassifier, self).__init__()

        self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(768, 5)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, input_id, mask):

        _, pooled_output = self.bert(input_ids= input_id, attention_mask=mask,return_dict=False)
        dropout_output = self.dropout(pooled_output)
        linear_output = self.linear(dropout_output)
        final_layer = self.relu(linear_output)

        return final_layer
    
from torch.optim import Adam
from tqdm import tqdm

def trainer(model, train_data, val_data, learning_rate, epochs):

    train, val = Dataset(train_data), Dataset(val_data)
    
    train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train, batch_size=2, shuffle=True)
    val_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val, batch_size=2)

    use_cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()
    device = torch.device("cuda" if use_cuda else "cpu")

    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = Adam(model.parameters(), lr= learning_rate)

    if use_cuda:

            model = model.cuda()
            criterion = criterion.cuda()

    for epoch_num in range(epochs):

            total_acc_train = 0
            total_loss_train = 0

            for train_input, train_label in tqdm(train_dataloader):

                train_label = train_label.to(device)
                mask = train_input['attention_mask'].to(device)
                input_id = train_input['input_ids'].squeeze(1).to(device)

                output = model(input_id, mask)
                
                batch_loss = criterion(output, torch.max(train_label,1)[1])
                total_loss_train += batch_loss.item()
                
                acc = (output.argmax(dim=1) == train_label).sum().item()
                total_acc_train += acc

                model.zero_grad()
                batch_loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()
            
            total_acc_val = 0
            total_loss_val = 0

            with torch.no_grad():

                for val_input, val_label in val_dataloader:

                    val_label = val_label.to(device)
                    mask = val_input['attention_mask'].to(device)
                    input_id = val_input['input_ids'].squeeze(1).to(device)

                    output = model(input_id, mask)

                    batch_loss = criterion(output, val_label)
                    total_loss_val += batch_loss.item()
                    
                    acc = (output.argmax(dim=1) == val_label).sum().item()
                    total_acc_val += acc
            
            print(
                f'Epochs: {epoch_num + 1} | Train Loss: {total_loss_train / len(train_data): .3f} \
                | Train Accuracy: {total_acc_train / len(train_data): .3f} \
                | Val Loss: {total_loss_val / len(val_data): .3f} \
                | Val Accuracy: {total_acc_val / len(val_data): .3f}')
                  
EPOCHS = 5
model = BertClassifier()
LR = 1e-6
              
trainer(model, df_train, df_val, LR, EPOCHS)
```

Comment: I'll admit, I don't understand what your `batch_y` is doing there in `__getitem__`... That method is supposed to return `(X, y)` for a given example from the underlying data source. You're creating the same `y` every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a list of length 33 in your `__getitem__` call which is one more than the length of the labels list, hence the out of bounds error. In fact, you create *the same* list each time this method is called. You're supposed to fetch the associated `y` with the `X` found at `idx`.

If you replace `batch_y = np.array(range(...))` with `batch_y = np.array(self.labels[idx])`, you'll fix your error. Indeed, this is already implemented in your `get_batch_labels` method.